# jQuery .eq() issue with hidden elements?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to iterate over two or more layers, fading one out and the next in.
At the start, both layers have the style "display:none;" - therefore, at the first method call, I just fadeIn() element .eq(0) - after that, I always fadeOut() .layer:visible and fadeIn() .eq(currentSlide).
currentSlide was initialized with 0 before and gets iterated at each call.

A no-brainer, one would think.
But here is what happens:
Whenever the animation starts, the first element gets faded in *twice* - after that the animation runs as expected, *but* the elements are in different order. The first element in the markup suddenly is .eq(1) and the second one is at index .eq(0).

If I remove display:none; from the layers, everything works perfect - it must be related to the visibility settings and maybe a selector not seeing the layers?
(But .children().length() always gives me the correct number though...)

The markup:

```
<div class="elements">
  <div class="layer"><img src="uploads/pics/one.png" /></div>
  <div class="layer"><img src="uploads/pics/two.png" /></div>
</div>
```

The jQuery plugin method written in coffescript:

```
   if element.find('.layer:visible').length > 0 and element.find('.elements').children().length > 1
    element.find('.layer:visible').fadeOut -> element.find('.elements').children().eq(currentSlide).fadeIn()
  else
    element.find('.elements').children().eq(0).fadeIn()

  # Iterate over slides or reset to zero if last one is reached
  if currentSlide < element.find('.elements').children().length - 1
    currentSlide++
  else
    currentSlide = 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write

```
element.find('.layer:visible').fadeOut ->
  element.find('.elements').children().eq(currentSlide).fadeIn()
```

there's a delay (by default, 400ms) before the callback is invoked. During that time, the `currentSlide` increment code is called; so `eq(currentSlide)` is called with that value, rather than the value of `currentSlide` when `fadeOut` was called.

Does this explain the behavior you're experiencing? Try substituting

```
slide = currentSlide
element.find('.layer:visible').fadeOut ->
  element.find('.elements').children().eq(slide).fadeIn()
```

Comment: Amazing. That's it!
I added an iterate() method and called it as a callback after the fadeIn(). Now it works perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

my html markup, which I think is what you have according to your coffee script (let me know if I inferred wrong!):

```
<div class="elements">
 <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="layer"><img src="uploads/pics/one.png" /></div>
  <div class="layer"><img src="uploads/pics/two.png" /></div>
 </div>
 <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="layer"><img src="uploads/pics/one.png" /></div>
  <div class="layer"><img src="uploads/pics/two.png" /></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var elementFirstKids = $('elements > element > layer:first-child');
  var elementOtherKids = $('elements > element > layer').not('elements > element > layer:first-child');
   elementFirstKids.fadeIn();
   elementOtherKids.fadeOut();
```